Can I train and import custom models (e.g. yet unsupported languages) in Google ML-Kit Digital Ink?
I haven't found any api or anything in the docs, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.
I have a client who intends to have recognition of a custom character set. For purposes of this question, you could assume I'm trying to recognize Klingon.
I would be happy to train a model myself, but I'm asking if there is an intended way to use it with ML Kit (more specific in Flutter).

Custom models are not supported by ML Kit Digital Ink at the moment.
